# React redux, action payload cannot see variable within a try/catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

I'm trying to put the variable "result" in the action payload but it cannot be defined because it is within the try block. I'm not sure how to work around this. I'm still new to Redux and here is the action itself.

```
export const fetchMovies = async (endpoint, category) => {
    const isLoadMore = endpoint.search('page');
    try{
        const result = await (await fetch(endpoint)).json();
    } catch(error){
        this.setState({error: true});
        console.log(error);
    }

    return{
        type: HomeActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES,
        payload: result, category, isLoadMore
    }
}
```

I've tried initializing result at the top using let but it did not resolve the issue. Also, I'm not sure if I'm setting the payload correctly with the variables I have set within them. For example, they are needed to be used within the reducer and my guess is to call the items within the payload as action.payload.result, action.payload.category, action.payload.isLoadMore wherever I need to use them within the reducer. Is that the correct way to do it? Thanks for any contributions to helping answer my questions.

Comment: Redux is confusing, but keep in mind that with this approach, part of your app is going to make the request action (fetchMovies), and then be stuck waiting while your fetch request completes. That's why you often see a pattern of sending a request, which returns a 'loading' state action, followed by a second action of success or error. There are various middleware out there that enable this pattern.

Comment: Yes, I have a loading spinner component for this while the app fetches the data. I only didn't include it here to simplify my code and question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take different approaches. First one, the one you are trying, you must declare the variable `result` as `let` (so you can modify its value) in the correspondent lexical scope, so in this case outside of the `try` brace and inside the function declaration so the `return` can access its value.

```
export const fetchMovies = async (endpoint, category) => {
    const isLoadMore = endpoint.search('page');
    let result = null
    try{
        result = await (await fetch(endpoint)).json();
    } catch(error){
        this.setState({error: true});
        console.log(error);
    }

    return{
        type: HomeActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES,
        payload: result, category, isLoadMore
    }
}
```

Another approach, that I'd rather follow, would be to move all the logic of the happy flow in the `try` brace and manage the action returned in the error flow in the `catch` brace:

```
export const fetchMovies = async (endpoint, category) => {
    try{
        const isLoadMore = endpoint.search('page');
        const result = await (await fetch(endpoint)).json();
        return{
          type: HomeActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES,
          payload: result, category, isLoadMore
        }
    } catch(error){
        // Rather than modifying the state, use a defined error action to trigger the proper error flow and logic.
        console.log(error);
        return{
          type: HomeActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR, // To be defined in the way you desire to be able to manage it as the execution of this action
          payload: error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you. I tried using the let before and I now realized it wasn't working for me because I left the const before the "result" within the try block. Thanks for clarifying this for me.